# Kendo UI Editor - open event

Tags: kendo-ui

With the Kendo UI editor a user can click the "insert image" button and the imagebrowser will popup.

I'd like to have the imagebrowser open when a user clicks a div - external from the editor.
How can I do this? Is it possible?

I've tried searching for ages but can't seem to find any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to come back to update this post but in the end, I used the Kendo Editor and hid everything. Here's what I did and hopefully this helps someone else one day:

```
.k-editable-area
{
    display: none;
}

.k-editor
{
    width: 4% !important;
    height: 28px !important;
    border: none !important;
    background-image: none;
    display: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.k-window
{
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   $("#imgBrowser").kendoEditor({
       tools: [
           "insertImage"
       ],
       imageBrowser: {
           messages: {
               dropFilesHere: "Drop files here"
           },
           transport: {
               read: "/ImageBrowser/Read",
               destroy: {
                   url: "/ImageBrowser/Destroy",
                   type: "POST"
               },
               create: {
                   url: "/ImageBrowser/Create",
                   type: "POST"
               },
               thumbnailUrl: "/ImageBrowser/Thumbnail",
               uploadUrl: "/ImageBrowser/Upload",
               imageUrl: "/ImageBrowser/Image?path={0}"
           },
           change: function () {
               //this.value(); //Selected image URL
           },
           select: function () {
           }
       }, execute: function (e) {           
       },
       change: function () {
       },
       select: function () {
           //this.value(); //Selected image URL but each selection is appended... ie:             
           <img /> <img /> <img /> ... you need to replace all except the last one.

           SetSelectedImage(this.value());

       }
   });
```

});

Then I added a link which when clicked, triggers the image browser:

```
 <a id="imgBrowser"></a><a id="addImage" style="display: inline; cursor: pointer;    
 float: left; font-weight: bold">+ Add image</a>
```

And finally, I added the javascript to do the triggering:

```
 $("#addImage").click(function () {
   $(".k-tool-icon").trigger('click');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. On focus of your text box, call below jQuery script.

```
$('#editor').parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.k-insertImage').click();
```

you can check on this link: [kendo editor](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/api.html).
Just call this script from your browser console.

Comment: Thanks, but in the end I figured out I could just use this:   $(".k-tool-icon").trigger('click');